# form is getting submmited when cleared

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a JSP page with multiple form elements (textbox,drpdown menu,textarea etc), I want to clear them on click of a button, i have written the below JavaScript code:

```
function clearForm(frm){
    alert("in clear form");
     $("textarea").val("");
     document.getElementById("City").selectedIndex = 0;
     document.getElementById('STREET_NAME').value="";
     return false;
    }
```

### JSP code:

```
<form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/insertData.htm" id="myForm">
//here i have form elemetns like textbox, dropdown meny,text area etc.

  <button name="clearButton" id="clearButton" onclick="return clearForm(this.form);">CLEAR</button> 
  <button name="buttonName" type="submit" id="submitButton" value="submit">SAVE</button>

</form>
```

When I click on CLEAR button, its going to JavaScript `clearForm(frm)` function ,clear the fields, then the form is getting submitted and the control is going to the controller class(Spring controller).Where I am going wrong, the form should not get submitted.

### --EDITED--

When I use the below code , only textarea field is getting cleared.

```
function clearForm(frm){

     $("textarea").val("");
     document.getElementById("City").selectedIndex = 0;
     document.getElementById('STREET_NAME').value="";
     return false;
    }
<button type="button" style="font-size:9px; height:20px;text-transform:uppercase;" name="clearButton" id="clearButton" onclick="return clearForm()">CLEAR</button>
```

Please find the same in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9uGv/)

Comment: Assuming your form starts off empty, you don't need javascript for this. `<button name="clearButton" type="reset">CLEAR</button>`

Comment: Your problem is, that function returning `false` to the button, not to the form.

Comment: See what KevinB said.  Your "clear" button does not contain a `type` attribute.  `type="button"` (with your JavaScript) or `type="reset"` (without any JavaScript) would take care of this.

Comment: The most likely cause of it submitting anyway though is a javascript error preventing the return false from happening, however i don't see anything that should be causing an error.

Comment: @KevinB, AFAIK, without specifying the `type`, it defaults to `submit` according to MDN:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Right, but the return false would stop that submit from happening wouldn't it?

Comment: @Kevin B, No. The `return false` only stops from submitting when its on the form `<form onSubmit='return false'>` not when its on the button.

Comment: @developerwjk, [look at this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7TBW2/3/).  I intentionally made it a `type="submit"`, but also made sure that the function appears in the `body`.  The form does not submit.  http://jsfiddle.net/7TBW2/3/

Comment: @Sparky, The fiddle is broken. I gave the form an action='www.google.com' and clicked the 'save' button and it didn't go to google.com

Comment: @developerwjk, my jsFiddle is not broken.  What you attempted is just not allowed:  http://jsfiddle.net/Zjg4c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), without specifying a `type` attribute, a `<button>` element defaults to `type="submit"`.

Add `type="reset"` to your button, and you won't need any JavaScript to clear out the form.

```
<button type="reset"  name="clearButton" id="clearButton">CLEAR</button>
```

Otherwise, add `type="button"`…

```
<button type="button" name="clearButton" id="clearButton" onclick="return false;">CLEAR</button>
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/7TBW2/2/

---

**EDIT:**

As per OP's comments as to why [his jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9uGv/) is not working.

OP's HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="relName" value="REL100" required="true" />
<textarea name="NOTES" cols="50" rows="4" />aklsdjj</textarea>
```

OP's JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('relName').value = "";
$("textarea").val("");
```

You have lots of errors and inconsistencies:

1)  `document.getElementById('relName')` is looking for the `id` attribute, but you don't have an `id` on this `input`, only a `name` attribute.

Add an `id`:

```
<input type="text" name="relName" id="relName" value="REL100" required="true" />
```

2)  `$("textarea")` is a jQuery selector but you don't have any jQuery library included in your jsFiddle.  Not sure why you would be mixing jQuery selectors with `getElementById()` in the first place, so I assume you're not really using jQuery for anything.

Use jQuery or don't, just be consistent:

```
document.getElementById("NOTES").value = "";
```

3)  Your HTML is invalid on the `textarea`.  You do not need a "self-closing" slash inside the *opening* tag since `textarea` is a container element.

It should be:

```
<textarea name="NOTES" id="NOTES" cols="50" rows="4">aklsdjj</textarea>
```

**FIXED**:  http://jsfiddle.net/z9uGv/2/

Comment: Thanks all. finally i used @kevin B post, as when iam writing the clearForm() javascript function and manaully clearing the fields by assigning to "" , fields are not getting cleared,only text area is gettign cleared, not sure where iam wrong.Please see the code in the above post.

Comment: @user3633028, you're going to have to show the relevant HTML so we can demo this.